# Inconsistent forecast result using DNN model in GCP Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, random-seed

I am using a DNN model for price forecasting in Google Cloud Functions. However, every time I run the model, I am getting different forecast results, even when using the same input data.

Here is an overview of my model:
==> I have a dataset with historical prices, where the train and test split are done inside the function.
==> I used TensorFlow and Keras to build the DNN model with several layers and neurons.
==> In Google Cloud Functions, I loaded the whole script to make price forecasts.
==> We added the following code snippets:

```
SEED = 123
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(SEED)
tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed(SEED)
tf.config.experimental.enable_op_determinism()
```

When we added these code snippets, I got consistent results locally but not on GCP cloud functions.

Request:
I am using the same input data every time I make a request to the cloud function, but I am getting different forecast results. This is causing problems for my application.

Can someone please help me understand why I am getting inconsistent results and how I can fix this issue? Thank you in advance!